# Prevent malicious user from executing JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In my JSP I have a function like `fnGetTicketDetails`:

```
function fnGetTicketDetails(record){
    $("#TicketNumber").val(record);
    $("#TicketDetailsForm").submit();
    return false;
}
```

I have form like this:

```
<form name="TicketDetailsForm" id="TicketDetailsForm" method="post" action='${properties["SUBMIT_TICKET_DETAIL"]}'
    target="_blank" style="display: none;">
```

I have an input hidden parameter

```
<input type="hidden" name="record" id="TicketNumber" />
```

It is working fine in the server. Issue was: If I use

```
javascript:eval("fnGetTicketDetails(83769551); eval();");
```

in the browser then also I am getting the details, which is invalid. How to block these type of request from browser. Because a hacker can easily get the details if he knows the ticket number.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. Try to avoid formatting *everything* as source code since it makes the questions less readable.

Comment: I don't understand the `eval`s there. Why not just `javascript:fnGetTicketDetails(83769551)`?

Comment: Nobody will use `eval()` to inspect hidden fields. It's way easier to use Firebug or any of its clones.

Answer (score 7):

You can't prevent the user from doing this.

You **must** treat all input from the user *including* all requests sent by *your JavaScript* as untrusted.

That means that the **server** *must* verify that the request from the user is legitimate (i.e. it must check if the current user has permission to read the specified detail).

Relying on hidden fields and JavaScript to keep your data secure is a very easy way of getting your data stolen.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Any data stored on the client is going to be visible to the end user.

The issue here is that your server is willing to show the details to anyone who asks for them. Don't even try to stop the user asking. Just do a check server side to make sure that that user is allowed to view those ticket details. If they're not, don't deliver them!